# Are there any open-source implementations of the Mercator Web Crawler

Tags: java, web-crawler

Marc Najork and Allan Heydon have written an excellent paper on their Java, scalable and extensible web crawler called Mercator.

Here are some resources on the Mercator web crawler:

- [Mercator Presentation (pdf)](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~lusec001/presentations/mercator_join.pdf)
- [Mercator Introduction (pdf)](http://coitweb.uncc.edu/~sakella/courses/cloud09/papers/Mercator.pdf)
- [Mercator Web Crawler Paper (pdf)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.163.9242&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
  First result in Google for the query: "Web Crawling Contents Najork pdf"

Has anybody seen any implementations of the crawler (preferably java)?

**Update:**
<strike>I'm</strike> I was having trouble with the links, <strike>I'm going to try to get better links for the referenced papers.</strike> but I think I've fixed them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a couple of Java crawlers that are supposed to be pretty close to Mercator:

- [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is multithreaded and distributed.
- [Heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org/index.html) is only multithreaded.

Other references are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

- Crawler4j - http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/
- WebSPHINX - http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rcm/websphinx/

Answer (score 0):

[StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net) is an open source SDK for building low-latency, distributed web crawlers with [Apache Storm](http://storm.apache.org). The project is under Apache license v2 and consists of a collection of reusable resources and components, written mostly in Java.